# C: Function in an if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I want to do something like this:

```
 if([FUNCTION] > 3){
         //do stuff
 }
```

where `FUNCTION` is a function that performs some action and returns the result as an int.  For example, function can be defined as:

```
 a + 1;
 return a;
```

where `a` was a previously defined variable.  Is there any way to do this in C?  Many thanks!

Comment: Whats wrong with `if(doSomething() > 3){}`?

Comment: Best you can do is to find some book to learn the very fundamental basics of programming in [tag:C].

Comment: In `if(expression)`, expression should result in true/false decision which is fine in your case.

Answer (score 3):

First of all

```
a + 1;
```

is a statement with no effect, so I'm assuming you meant `a = a + 1`. Then yes, you can of course call a function from within an if statement.

```
int foo(int* a) {
  *a = *a + 1;
  return *a;
}

// later ...

int a = 7;
if (foo(&a) > 3) {
  // do stuff
}
```

If `a` is not known in the scope of the if statement, you probably meant something like this:

```
int a = 7;

int foo() {
  a = a + 1;
  return a;
}

// later ...

if (foo() > 3) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Just as an amendment: `a += 1` or `a++` or `++a` would be valid as well.

Comment: @glglgl: Yes, but I used the code of the OP so they would recognise where `a + 1` went, as I assume that was just an example.

Comment: Hmm. a=a+1 increments the *pointer* a... something is wrong here.

Comment: @Jens: `*a = *a + 1` if you pass a pointer, and `a = a + 1` if you access the global variable directly.

Answer (score 2):

Since grammatically, C allows `if ( expression )` and a function call on the left of a *relational expression* with `>` is an expression as well, the answer is yes, you can do this in the straightforward way,

```
if (some_function() > 3) {
    /* Do stuff. */
}
```

What kind of C book is it that doesn't make this clear? I highly recommend Kernighan, Ritchie, *The C Programming Language*, 2nd Edition (update for ANSI/ISO C89).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a=5;
int foo(int a)
{
    a++;
    return a;
}

int main()
{

    if(foo(a) > 3) {
       printf("%d\n",a);
       // Do stuff
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's simple.

EDIT :It's just a demo source code to show that `if` condition returns `true`.

Comment: No indentation *and* no braces? Bad.

Comment: @Lundin : I have just given a demo .So that It will enter into the `if` condtion. I think OP will get the point . I know that it's not necessary to be `5`.And I think you know that too

Comment: Yeah I realize that, but when dealing with obvious beginners, one shouldn't lure them into using bad programming practice.